# Javascript onClick( ) function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I will be adding a list of contacts and put them in a div based on first character of **lname**. If the div doesn't exists, it will be created dynamically. I'd want to display the contact information on clicking the name. In the following implementation, `showMe( )` function not working to display the contact information .

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
 .holder{
     background-color:yellow;
     margin-top:10px;
     width: 300px;
}

.holder span{
   background-color: Green;  
   height:20px;
   color:white;
  }

 </style>



<script>

var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");

    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    };
    contacts.push(person);  

    var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length-1]; //take the last pushed object from the array

    var lastNameFirstChar = currPerson.lname.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

    if(!document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder")){      
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  id='"+lastNameFirstChar+"_holder' class='holder'><span>"+lastNameFirstChar+"</span></br></div>";

  }
   //document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHTML += currPerson.fname+" "+currPerson.lname + "<br/>";


   document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHTML += "<span onclick='showMe(" + currPerson.id + ")'>" + currPerson.fname + " " + currPerson.lname + "</span><br/>";


}


function showMe(id) {
    alert(id);
   var person = contacts[id];  /* currently corresponds to array index, could be a property lookup with underscore or whatever */
   var contactInfo = person.fname+" "+person.lname+"</br> "+person.email+"</br>"+person.phone;

   target.innerHTML = "<div>" + contactInfo + "</div></br>";

}





</script>

</head>

<body>
<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Person Info</button>
<p>----------------------------</p>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus This line invokes `document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHTML += "<span onclick='showMe(" + currPerson.id + ")'>" + currPerson.fname + " " + currPerson.lname + "</span><br/>";`

Comment: This is really not the best way to solve your problem. Instead of inline HTML event handlers, you should be using element.addEventListener. And, instead of using JavaScript to write new HTML elements and wire them up, you should just create the element, either via document.createElement or have it precreated, but just not displayed. Then the JavaScript only has to wire it up to the event handler (again using addEventListener).

Comment: There is no `id` property in your persons and `target` in `showMe()` is `undefined`

Comment: There is not `currPerson.id` in the person object, it is undefined when the function `showMe` is called.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik It works here [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67d2bdd1264cf09198a2) In this div are not created dynamically. I think my approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call showMe() function you are supposed to send  the id of the person by currPerson.id
but when you defined var person you didn't give it the id property.
you have this

```
var person = {
            fname: firstName,
            lname: lastName,
            email: emailId,
            phone: phoneNo
        };
```

make it like this

```
var person = {
            id: contacts.length,// note this extra parameter
            fname: firstName,
            lname: lastName,
            email: emailId,
            phone: phoneNo
        };
```

now when you call

```
"<span onclick='showMe(" + currPerson.id + ")'>"
```

currentPerson.id will not be undefined anymore.

Secondly when you call this line

```
target.innerHTML = "<div>" + contactInfo + "</div></br>";
```

you haven't defined the variable "target".

add this line before the above line

```
var target= document.getElementById("mydiv")
```

where "myDiv" is the id of what you defined in the html markup

```
<div id="mydiv">
```

Comment: It works here [link] (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67d2bdd1264cf09198a2) In this div are not created dynamically. I think I need to change my approach completely.

Comment: @Droidr in that case just add 
<div id="target" style="float: right;"> </div>
just under 
<div id="mydiv"></div>
and remove this line from answer
var target= document.getElementById("mydiv")
and things will work. I'll update the answer as well

Comment: Still it doesn't work. because the parameter id is undefined.

Comment: @Droidr did you add this line
id: contacts.length
this is also on line 14 on the link you gave above where its working

Comment: It works in the above link. But not in above posted code or here [DynamicDiv] (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe2c5d6988b9ee5bd301)

Comment: @Droidr Please stop copy paste from different sites, You are not getting the logic here. Have you even read my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried your answer and it works. But I don't understand why it doesn't work in both of the links posted. I didn't copy paste from somewhere else. Both of the links are posted by me. But your answer works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>

        var contacts = [];

        function getInfo()
        {
            var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
            var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
            var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
            var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");

            var person = {
                fname: firstName,
                lname: lastName,
                email: emailId,
                phone: phoneNo
            };
            contacts.push(person);

            var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length - 1]; //take the last pushed object from the array
            var id = contacts.length - 1;
            var lastNameFirstChar = currPerson.lname.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

            if (!document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder"))
            {
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  id='" + lastNameFirstChar + "_holder' class='holder'><span>" + lastNameFirstChar + "</span></br></div>";

            }
            //document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHML += currPerson.fname+" "+currPerson.lname + "<br/>";


            document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHTML += "<span onclick='showMe(" + id + ")'>" + currPerson.fname + " " + currPerson.lname + "</span><br/>";


        }


        function showMe(id)
        {
            //alert(id);
            var person = contacts[id];  /* currently corresponds to array index, could be a property lookup with underscore or whatever */
            var contactInfo = person.fname + " " + person.lname + "</br> " + person.email + "</br>" + person.phone;

            mydiv.innerHTML = "<div>" + contactInfo + "</div></br>";

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: It works. But it makes the existing  contact list disappear from the page

Comment: I don't understand where the **id** coming from . Can you explain?

Comment: var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length - 1]; here we are creating a new object from existing one using contacts.length-1 which is actually pointing to index of object.same way i used it below to access object via id. you needed an index so i stored it to a variable and just passed it on to the function.

Comment: oops. I didn't notice this `var id = contacts.length - 1;` . But can you explain how it's working here (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67d2bdd1264cf09198a2)

Comment: i am storing id apart from the object and in that code it is stored within object itself. in both code id is only used to access contacts with specific index(i.e.id)

Comment: Got you. My bad I didn't notice that.Thanks

Comment: Could you tell if sorting the list as shown (http://imgur.com/EoBZQmW) is possible? I want to sort the list in alphabetical order. I think it's not possible with the current approach ?

Comment: this will give you object as per alphabetical order of email contacts.sort(function(a,b) {
    return (a.email>b.email);
});